# Why indexOf + charAt method shows -1

Tags: javascript

```
function unique_char(str1)
{
var str=str1;
var uniql="";
for (var x=0;x < str.length;x++)
 {

if(uniql.indexOf(str.charAt(x))==-1)
  {
uniql += str[x];  

}
}
return uniql;  
}  
console.log(unique_char("thequickbrownfoxjumpsoverthelazydog"));
```

This code is from: https://www.w3resource.com/javascript-exercises/javascript-function-exercise-16.php

I dont get this, why do we compare to -1 and this shows true?

Comment: Did you read the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)?

Comment: `.indexOf()` returns `-1` when the searched-for string is not in the searched string.

Comment: @Pointy thank you very much :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the documentation for .indexOf() states, .indexOf(searchValue) returns -1 if searchValue is not found anywhere.

http://devdocs.io/javascript/global_objects/string/indexof